# Laravel authentication with uppercase table name like 'AUTHS'

Tags: laravel, authentication, customization

Recently I was working on a project where the requirement was that I have to use all table names along with columns in uppercase. I can authenticate with uppercase columns and lowercase table name(auths), no problem. When I use "AUTHS" it does not seem to work. I can not find any references that match my requirements. If anyone can help me, it will be appreciated. Thank you.

laravel version - 6.20.19

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'AUTHS';

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->PASSWORD;
    }
}

public function postLogin(LoginRequest $request)
    {
$email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        $user = \App\Models\Auth::where(['EMAIL' => $email])->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('USER_TYPE', 0);
        })->first();

        $credentials = $request->only('EMAIL', 'password');
        if ($this->hasExist($user)) {
            $remember_me  = ( !empty( $request->remember_me ) ) ? true : false;

            if ($this->auth->attempt(['EMAIL' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember_me))
            {
                return redirect('dashboard');
            }
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors([
            'EMAIL' => 'The credentials you entered did not match our records. Try again?',
        ]);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see some of your code, particularly your User model. Also what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: "_where the requirement was that I have to use all table names along with columns in uppercase_" What kind of requirement is that? What's the reason behind this?

Comment: @brombeer I have no idea :(
I've spent a whole day figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant by `use "AUTHS"` but if you are accessing the tables through Models, you can overwrite the default table names like so:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'my_flights';
}
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#table-names

Comment: Thank you, but I want to use table name in uppercase.

Comment: I updated my question, there you can see my code

Answer (score 0):

I've found my problem. I did not declare my custom primary key.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'AUTHS';
    protected $primaryKey = 'PK_NO';

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->PASSWORD;
    }
}
```